# force Image fill all part of SimpleDraweeView area

Tags: android, fresco, scaletype

When I load an image into `SimpleDraweeView` in `fresco` liberary it tries to show all image in it so images corners remain empty, How can I force it to scale image to fill whole area?
I tried most of `fresco:actualImageScaleType` but nothing changes at all.here is my layout

I have set `scaleType` to `centerCrop`  and nothing changed

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">



    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="0dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">



        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.10">
                    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                        android:id="@+id/img_main"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/backgrondlayout2"
                        fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#42000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                            android:text="Header"
                            android:transitionName="title"
                            android:id="@+id/txt_header"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:padding="@dimen/textPadding"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/textPadding"
                            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
                            android:textColor="@color/off_white" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                </FrameLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:layout_weight="0.0001"
                    android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="109dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.10">
                        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                            android:id="@+id/img_logo"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                           />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.90">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"
                            android:text="Discription"
                            android:id="@+id/txt_discription"
                            android:paddingRight="4dp"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_weight="0.99"
                    android:gravity="right|center_horizontal"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
                    android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:weightSum="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1.75"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_distance_icon"
                            android:contentDescription=""
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            tools:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_directions_black_24dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="52dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.35"
                        android:gravity="center|right">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="0.0 km"
                            android:id="@+id/txt_distance"
                            android:layout_weight="0.77"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/textPadding"
                            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/textPadding"
                            android:maxLines="1" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="Indoor"
                            android:id="@+id/txt_indoor"
                            android:gravity="center|right"
                            android:textColor="#e00b0b"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:paddingRight="4dp"
                            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout></android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>`
```

and this is what it shows
[image]

Can you please help me find my mistake?
thanks